# Calling a mixin function from the store

Tags: vue.js, mixins, vuex

I am trying to make a call to api from a vue component. I am making that call via the vuex store (since i read that is good practice).

In the store action i would like to interact with an error handling function I have as a mixin function in the vue instance. But i can only do this if i pass the full vue instance to the store call like so: `this.$store.dispatch('store/get', this);`

The call to the mixin is something like this:

```
get: function(context, object) {
       ...
            object.catchError(error)
```

I would like to avoid to pass `this` in the dispatch, but still be able to access the mixin function. Is this possible or should i be doing things differently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Call the action like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('store/get')
 .then(r => {
        // r contains the result, but you can call here the getter as well..
    })
 .catch(e => {
        // catch every error here, you can handle here the error.
});
```

And the getter function is like this:

```
get: function(context) {
   return axios.get(/api/call/get)
    .then(r => {
        ... // mutations, conditions of data check.. throwing errors..
        return r;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        throw e;
    })
}
```

I hope my thought is clear, but if it is not, comment your question(s)! :)